# Forward declaring and using in one step

Tags: c++

As an optimisation, or to avoid include looping, a type may be forward declared, This leads to code like:

```
class A;

class B
{
    A *a;
};
```

If the number of forward declaration becomes large, it can take up a lot of space at the top of the header file. Is there a way of forward declaring and using at the same time?  Sort of like:

```
class B
{
    extern A *a;
};
```

I've never really thought about this before, but I have a header with a bunch of forward declarations and I would like to make it tidier (without farming them off to another include file).

EDIT: I changed 'a' to a pointer, as it was rightly pointed out that you can only use forward declare on pointers and references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're asking isn't completely clear but, if I understand you right, you can forward declare *at the same time* as declaring your variables:

```
class B
{
    class A* a; // declaring A as class is an in-place forward declaration
};
```

Is that what you mean?

Comment: Interesting, I have never seen this syntax used before.

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was looking for, and, no, I've never seen anything like it before. It helped clean up my header file.

Answer (score 4):

A forward declaration wouldn't allow you to do

```
class A;

class B
{
    A a;
};
```

unless `A` is a reference or pointer type, since a forward declaration doesn't give any additional information on the size of the object (unless for `enum class` in C++11). So are you using pointers/references? Otherwise it means you are including the definition of `A` for sure.

Regarding your problem there is no way to forward declare and use a type since we're talking about two different things. A variable declaration doesn't define a type, it defines a variable.

A simple solution to your problem would be to gather all forward declaration in a single header file and include it in the project (or in your eventual precompiled header). This wouldn't create too much problems, since forward declarations don't expose anything nor they are heavyweight.

Comment: Sorry, dumb mistake in my example.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do what you want. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4757718/2589844) about forward declarations should give you all the gory details, but in summary you need the full definition of a type if you want to use it (as including more or less does); not just the fact that it exists (as forward declaring more or less does).

Comment: Sorry, my example was broken.